# How to fix google console interface compute engine delete action using up request limits (compute.instances.listReferrers)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-api-client

Using the webinterface of console.cloud.google.com to delete one Compute Engine VM instance triggers roughly 5 `compute.instances.listReferrers` requests per second for roughly 5 minutes. These spikes in api usage can be observed under "APIs & Services" -> "Metrics" (change to 1 hour, to improve visibility). I'm looking for a way to not trigger this many requests, for those can easily lock me out of the "2k requests per 100 seconds" quota.

VM specs:

- region us-east1 zone us-east1-b
- 8vCPUs, 7.2GB memory
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Minimal
- preemtibility ON

Deleting the VM instance under "Compute Engine" -> "VM instances" -> three stacked dots on the right side of the vm row -> "Delete" -> "Delete an Instane, Are you sure that you want to delte instance 'X'? (This will also delete boot disk 'X')" -> "Delete"

Viewing activies in a different tab under "APIs & Services" -> "Metrics" (change to 1 hour, to improve visibility) shows a spike in activiy of `compute.instances.listReferrers` for several minutes afterwards.

I'm located in EU if that matters for this issue.

I expected to see a very short spike in activity, due to collection of resources that need to be deleted. But I didn't expect such a long duration of several minutes. If I delte multiple instances at the same time or in short succession, I'm breaking the allowed quota and can't create new instances for some time.

Finally, if someone knows a way of how this could be brought to the attention of the responsible google devs, please let me know too.

Comment: Please file an issue on Google's public issue tracker. I recommend this component: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187225. In order to avoid your observed excessive quota, you may wish to use `gcloud` part of the Cloud SDK  which likely won't suffer this issue.

Comment: @DazWilkin if you believe this is the correct solution, would you kindly post it as an answer? This will help other users within the community should they have the same inquiry,

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link. I lacked the time to check using `gcloud` too. Having to wait sometimes up to 30 minutes when trying to nail track down the origin of the request flood was pretty time consuming. I'll report back once I can try the command. Oh and I'll check the same using `googleapiclient` (python).